# How to parsing variable config to library class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to parse $ config to the class library

I try and I found error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: libraries/Mtransc.php
```

**This my controller:**

```
$config =   [
                    'credential' => 
                    [
                        'username' => $p1,
                        'password' => $p2
                    ],
                    'nomor_rekening' => '042359659142112',
                    'range' => 
                    [
                        'date_start'    => date('d-M-Y',strtotime($tgl1)),
                        'date_end'      => date('d-M-Y',strtotime($tgl2))
                    ],
                ];
    $this->load->library('Mtransc', $config);

    $bni = $this->mtransc($config);
    var_dump($bni->toArray());
```

**And this my library Mtransc.php:**

```
require_once('cekBNI/simple_html_dom.php');
class Mtransc{
    const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36";
    const urlPrepareLogin = 'https://ibank.bni.co.id/MBAWeb/FMB;jsessionid=0000bAQ5H6TjltF-OqrAf-Hv-9P:1a1li5jho?page=Thin_SignOnRetRq.xml&MBLocale=bh';
    private $ch;
    private $config;
    private $result;
    private $cookie ='cekBNI/bni-cookie.txt';
    private $dom;
    private $parameters;
    private $actionUrl;
    private $parsed;

    public function __construct($config){
        $this->config =& get_instance();
        try{
            $cookie = $this->cookie;
            $this->dom = new simple_html_dom();
            $this->config = $config;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, self::ua);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $this->ch = $ch;

            $this->prepareLogin();
            $this->login();
            $this->getMutasi();
            $this->logout();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Comment: which specific line is giving you this error?

Comment: pass variable through model insted of calling from controller. load model in your library like this `$this->config->load->model("model_name");`